# Is the series continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I'd like to determine whether $F(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges for all $x\in\Bbb R$

Using the M-test:

[image]

Finding $||f_n(x)||_{\infty}$:

$f'_n(x)=\frac{x'n(1+nx^2)-2n^2x^2}{(n(1+nx^2))^2}=\frac{n-n^2x^2}{(n+n^2x^2)^2}=0$

So, $x=+-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Hence, $|f_n(\sqrt{n}^{-1})|=\frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{n(1+n/n)}=\frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ and hence $\sum^{\infty}_0||f_n(x)||_{\infty}<\infty$

So the sum converges uniformly. If it converge uniformly, then by this theorem it's continuous?:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you just need to check that for each $n$, the function $f_n$ is bounded and continuous. Then your partial sums will be bounded and continuous and you'll then be able to apply the theorem.

Comment: @Ollie well, $f_n(x)\leq ||f||_{\infty}=1/n^{3/2}$ so it's bounded above by 1, but how do I show it's continuous?

Comment: So show continuity, write $f_n = g / h$ where $g,h$ are continuous functions. Then check that $h(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$

Comment: @Ollie ok, but i actually didn't need this theorem to show that the series is continuous? It actually doesn't prove anything, as in it doesn't prove the fact that the series is continuous? Isn't the fact that the series converges uniformly sufficient to say that it's continuous?

Comment: Yes, I think the Theorem that would be easiest to prove this, is the one that says: If $(f_i)_i$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $(f_i)$ converges uniformly, then the limit is continuous. The above theorem about Cauchy sequences does apply to your case too since the functions are all bounded and continuous.

Comment: @ yes but, if it's a _series_ of continuous functions, then can I say that the series is continuous?

Comment: So instead of treating it as a series, we can treat it a sequence of partials sums: $F_k(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^k f_i(x)$. Since each $f_i$ is continuous and the partial sums are finite, $F_k$ is also continuous

Comment: @Ollie okay thanks, this cleared it up!